# Pegando uma string de um XML que recebi de um http request

Tags: c#, xml

Então pessoal, a problema em mãos agora é que eu tenho que pegar duas linhas que estão em um XML, eu consigo esse XML por meio de um httpRequest, e ai aparentemente começa o problema.

O que eu tentei até agora foi:

...

```
[WebMethod]
public void PassaProtocolo(int numProtocolo) {
           string url = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("consulta");
            url = url + numProtocolo.ToString();//adiciona numero do protocolo no endereço do http request

            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);//acessa httprequest
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();//recebe pagina

            XDocument XmlDoc = XDocument.Load(url);
            string funfou = XmlDoc.Root.ToString();

}
```

...

o endereço que estou usando como a variável url ali já foi testado e retorna a pagina como deveria:

```
<RetornoOfConsultaProtocoloResultulvhizZy><Codigo i:nil="true"/><Descricao i:nil="true"/><Lista><d2p1:ConsultaProtocoloResult><d2p1:cNPJField/><d2p1:cPFField>34780831687</d2p1:cPFField><d2p1:codAssuntoField>17</d2p1:codAssuntoField><d2p1:codAssuntoFieldSpecified>true</d2p1:codAssuntoFieldSpecified>
```

-numeroAqui2017-02-24T00:00:00truenumeroaqui0true

Ao executar o codigo eu recebo o erro:

System.Xml.XmlException: Dados no nível raiz inválidos. Linha 1, posição 1.
   em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   em System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   em System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   em System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   em System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri)
   em wsIntegraCREA.ConsultaSGAasmx.PassaProtocolo(Int32 numProtocolo) na C:\Users\marcus\Dropbox\Projetos\Stoque\Clientes\CREA-MG\AtendimentoCREA_HOMOLOGACAO\wsIntegraCREA\ConsultaSGAasmx.asmx.cs:linha 41

Este ocorre quando o XDocument tenta carregar a url. Nunca tentei mecher com algo do gênero antes, então estou com um pouco de dificuldade, agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro acredito que a sua variável `url` não seja o seu XML retornado pelo *web service* e sim você deve ter o Xml no retorno do seu *response*.

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);//acessa httprequest
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();//recebe pagina

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()));
string funfou = xmlDoc.Root.ToString();
```